# How to render full templates in a div on a page in django

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

So I am working on a way for users to be able to customize their webpages in django. I want the left side of the page to be the part for customizing and the right side of the page to show the webpage that is being customized. So I'm trying to figure out how to get the right div to somehow serve as a body and render the django template document, if that makes any sense. So basically I'm am trying to render a html template page within a div, or only on part of a page. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You can use an iframe or AJAX.

Comment: what have you done so far !? can you show us your code ?